# Porting a piece of Lisp code to Clojure (PAIP)

Tags: clojure, lisp, artificial-intelligence, common-lisp

I'm reading *Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming* (PAIP) by Peter Norvig and I'm trying to write all the code in Clojure rather than common Lisp. However I'm stuck on this piece of code on page 39:

```
(defparameter *simple-grammar*
  '((sentence -> (noun-phrase verb-phrase))
   (noun-phrase -> (Article Noun))
   (verb-phrase -> (Verb noun-phrase))
   (Article -> the a)
   (Noun -> man ball woman table)
   (Verb -> hit took saw liked))
  "A grammar for a trivial subset of English.")

 (defvar *grammar* *simple-grammar*)
```

How can I translate this into Clojure? 
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know Clojure, but doesn't it quote list literals the same way?  Just change `defparameter` to `def`.  It looks like docstrings are supplied in a different way, though, and I'm not sure about that...

Comment: Looking at http://norvig.com/paip/simple.lisp, which is the source for your code, it *appears* that -> is not used in the actual code, but acts as syntactic sugar for the list of lists up there.

Comment: I made some of paip in clojure (more to came) https://github.com/nickik/ParadigmsOfAIProgramming

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm a relative Clojure newbie that went through this exact exercise a while back.  Something to consider here is whether you'd like to adhere as closely as possible to Norvig's code (like writing "Common-Lisp-flavored" Clojure) or if you'd like to write something closer to idiomatic Clojure.  Here's what I did:

```
(use '[clojure.contrib.def :only [defvar]])

(defvar *simple-grammar* 
  {:sentence [[:noun-phrase :verb-phrase]]
   :noun-phrase [[:Article :Noun]]
   :verb-phrase [[:Verb :noun-phrase]]
   :Article ["the" "a"]    
   :Noun ["man" "ball" "woman" "table"]
   :Verb ["hit" "took" "saw" "liked"]}
  "A grammar for a trivial subset of English.")
```

defvar is sugar that allows you to add docstrings to vars more naturally.  In this case I'm using a map (key value pairs delimited by {}) to get dictionary-style lookup from the LHS of each rule to the RHS.  I'm also using vectors (delimited by []) instead of lists to represent the RHS of each rule.  Generally speaking, "idiomatic" Clojure code rarely uses lists to hold sequential data; vectors are preferred unless you're representing Clojure forms (source code).

These kinds of changes will allow you to use more of the built-in power of the language instead of e.g., having to write little helper functions to manipulate nested lists.

Answer (score 5):

Ken's right, just a simple few changes to the def* forms, and a different style of docstring (docstrings are a bit simpler for function definitions than for normal vars):

```
(def ^{:doc "A grammar for a trivial subset of English."} 
  *simple-grammar*
  '((sentence -> (noun-phrase verb-phrase))
    (noun-phrase -> (Article Noun))
    (verb-phrase -> (Verb noun-phrase))
    (Article -> the a)
    (Noun -> man ball woman table)
    (Verb -> hit took saw liked)))

(def *grammar* *simple-grammar*)
```